# Including sub makefiles in a master makefile: variables changed in sub makefile do not reflect in master makefile

Tags: makefile, gnu-make

I've been debugging this problem for 2 days straight, and I'm about to lose my mind here. We have a master makefile that includes a bunch of sub makefiles. Among other things, these sub makefiles add stuff to a variable **EXTERNAL_LIBS**.

The adding to the variable happens like this:

```
EXTERNAL_LIBS += foo
```

or this

```
EXTERNAL_LIBS := bar $(EXTERNAL_LIBS)
```

The problem I'm having is that the values added to this **EXTERNAL_LIBS** variable by *some* sub makefiles are gone when I look at the **EXTERNAL_LIBS** variable in the master makefile (which happens AFTER all the sub makefiles have been included), while the values added by other sub makefiles are still there. I don't understand what's happening to the "lost" values.

I've grepped our entire codebase for occurrences of **EXTERNAL_LIBS** to make sure it doesn't get emptied out or otherwise overwitten somewhere, and it doesn't. Also, I know for sure that the sub makefiles in question do get evaluated as I've both added debug printouts and done a trace via the -d option to GNU Make.

Does anyone have an idea what I might be doing wrong here? We're using GNU Make 4.2 for Windows on a Windows 7 machine, by the way.

EDIT: I got it!!!! The root cause was my incomplete knowledge of how GNU Make functions. This link ( https://www.gnu.org/software/make/manual/html_node/Reading-Makefiles.html ) describes how variables initialized like this

```
EXTERNAL_LIBS = bla
```

will used deferred expansion when stuff is appended via `+=`, whereas variables initialized like this

```
EXTERNAL_LIBS := bla
```

will use immediate expansion. That was exactly the problem! Some makefiles used syntax like this:

```
MY_LIB_NAME = <some_fancy_function_call>
...
EXTERNAL_LIBS += $(MY_LIB_NAME)
```

and many makefiles reused the MY_LIB_NAME variable in that fashion. So I think what happened is that all these Makefiles didn't add the current value of $(MY_LIB_NAME) but the literal string "$(MY_LIB_NAME)", which then later got expanded to whatever the last makefile had set $(MY_LIB_NAME) to. I have now switched to immediate expansion by initializing the variable like this:

```
EXTERNAL_LIBS :=
```

hoping that this would enforce immediate expansion. I've also switched from `=` to `:=` when assigning the value to the variable that later shows up on the right hand side of EXTERNAL_LIBS, just to be sure. So far, this seems to have solved the problem for me. God, Make is going to drive me to an early grave one of these days.

Comment: Can't reproduce (Linux + make 4.2.1).

Comment: The funny thing is that I can't reproduce it either with any other variable. I introduced some test variables that do exactly the same thing, and they all behave exactly as one would expect. It's just this weird EXTERNAL_LIBS variable that displays this odd behavior, which makes me think that I must have missed some makefile that simply empties the variable out, but I've basically looked at every single one of our makefiles and didn't find any such thing. :(

Comment: Well, I guess there could be some obscure Makefile that does something like this:

`varNamePartOne = EXTERNAL`
`varNamePartTwo = LIBS`

`$($(varNamePartOne)_$(varNamePartTwo)) = haha fooled you`

but that would almost take criminal intentions.

Comment: Composing a variable name from the values of other variables isn't actually *that* unusual -- so probably worth looking into.  By way of a quick check you could try renaming all known references to `EXTERNAL_LIBS` to something like `EXTERNAL_LIBS_JHFG6475GFH` and see if that has any effect.  Also, do you have an environment variable named `MAKEFILES` set at all?

Comment: It would help if you post a complete minimal example which demonstrates the problem. Your text description is not enough.